# Getting download progress / currently downloaded bytes from an async GET with C# Httpclient

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, httpclient

I'm trying to get some download progress represented in Xamarin using System.Web.Http's httpclient. I understand in the typical case to get the file size in advance with a HEAD request and checking for the content-length of the file in question. What I don't understand is how to get the currently transferred file size so I can compare that against the total.

Is this possible? I've looked around for other examples, but they seem to be making use of WebClient or other such instead.

Edit:

```
submitButton.Clicked += async (object sender, EventArgs e) => {
var client = new HttpClient();

var url = (Just making use of a sizable wallpaper here as example.);

var result = await client.GetStreamAsync(url);
}
```

If I await the GetStreamAsync as above, then I can't perform any operations on the stream until it's done. If I remove the await and try to work with the Task result, the same thing takes place - even trying to get a Length won't work until the entire thing is completed anyway.

Obviously if I can get at the stream as it's being written to, I can check the length (hopefully) and just compare that to the header information. But how to access that mid-transfer, I do not get.

Comment: You can use *GetStreamAsync* async method of HttpClient and read your blocks using that stream.

Comment: But how would you implement that? Otherwise I'll be running into the same problem as with any other awaited async operation, where I can't get at anything until it's done (unless I write the method myself and have it updating something outside of itself.)

Comment: Joseph, When you read the stream in a loop, you *know* how many bytes you read. So What is hard in doing something like this:  `while(...){ total+=stream.Read(...); }`

Comment: Probably nothing, I was under the impression that an awaited async stream wouldn't give me access to the stream itself, just Task<Stream> with the stream unavailable until the task was done. I'll experiment with what you're suggesting.

Comment: Nope, I am not able to get this work so far. So if anyone knows of a simple working example, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: `Nope, I am not able to get this work so far` is not good fit for Stackoverflow. What have you tried? What did go wrong? Have you got an exception or is the output not like as you have expected?  I have code that does it with multiple threads in parallel using *System.Net.Http.HttpClient* for Win8.1 but it is not as simple as you expect and I prefer to fix your code instead of posting a wall of code.

Comment: Sortly it uses `GetStreamAsync` + `ReadAsync`. That is all.

Comment: Oh, you just want a code example from me? It would be my pleasure. I'll edit one into the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the best solution I've been able to find for this so far is "use Webclient instead of httpclient". I haven't been able to give Webclient a shot yet in Xamarin, and hopefully it will work there, but I managed to get progress working with it on the PC in a straightforward manner.